# SQL UPDATE with database values

Tags: sql

It is possible to UPDATE sql column with the actual values ?

EXAMPLE :

```
UPDATE TEST SET example = {actual_value}, other = 'test'
```

I want to replace {actual_value} with the actual value without ask sql server before update.

Comment: the actual value of what?

Comment: actual value of this row

Comment: Yeah but I mean, where does that actual value come from?

Comment: I think you just put the `UPDATE TEST SET example =COLUMNNAME, other = 'test'`

Comment: Why you want to update a value with it itself?

Comment: You tag MySQL but talk about sql server. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Yup, fail, remove mysql tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the answer thanks to @muasif80.

IF you want to update with actual value :

```
UPDATE TEST SET column_name = column_name
```